# Как добавлять правильно тег?

Tags: jquery

Есть код в котором я принимаю данные из PHP и по результату данных вставляю эти данные в ID.

Вопрос Как добавлять данные не заменяя их?

append  добавляеет каждый раз новый тег.

```
   if(data.towns==undefined) {
            var optionRayons = '';
            optionRayons = '<br><select id="selectRayons" name="Rayons" title="Выберете район"> <option value="">Выберете район</option>';
            for (var key in data.rayons) {
                optionRayons += '<option value="' + data.rayons[key] + '">' + data.rayons[key] + '</option>';
            }
            optionRayons += '</select><br>';
            $("#detale").html(optionRayons);
        }
        else {
            var optionTowns = '';
            optionTowns = '<br><select id="selectTowns" name="Towns" title="Выберете город"> <option value="">Выберете район</option>';
            for (var town in data.towns) {
                optionTowns += '<option value="' + data.towns[town] + '">' + data.towns[town] + '</option>'
            }
            optionTowns += '</select><br>';
            $("#detale").html(optionTowns);
        }
```

Comment: имей на странице select и вставляй в него сформированные option

Comment: _Вопрос Как добавлять данные не заменяя их?_, _append добавляет каждый раз новый тег._ - похоже ты сам ответил на свой вопрос

Comment: @Grundy , дело в том что я постоянно запрашиваю данные по событию сhange, и когда я это сделю то добавляется новый тег а хотелось что бы он вставился, по результатам данных.

Comment: _добавляется новый тег а хотелось что бы он вставился, по результатам данных_ - попробуй подробнее описать то что ты хочешь, сейчас совсем непонятно что требуется